# Google Ecommerce Tracking for Magento

Tags: magento, google-analytics, e-commerce

I am having some difficulty in getting google's eCommerce tracking working consistently for Magento. I have set the UA code in the google api section of the admin and eCommerce tracking is switched on. When I go to the success page the code is there. Some orders are being sent but not all. I have installed google chromes analytics tester and the beacon is being sent. Take yesterdays orders for example, 1 from sagepay is in analytics however another sagepay order is not which rules out payment gateway. I have re-set the permissions on the success page and tidied up a couple of warnings in the console but nothing is working i'm pretty stumped.

I have also installed Jiraffe real-time analytics and am having the same problem with that tracking orders, it didn't track a single order yesterday but is tracking cart data fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Two sagepay orders you were talking about above, are those two orders placed as guest or registered or each of one? The reason I was asking because sagepay community module has had a bug with order placed as guest which has been resolved in their latest release

Answer (score 0):

First of all not every user who uses payment gateway is comming back to your success page as some of them are just leaving the transaction at thank you page on third party services - then you won't see such transaction in GA. Second of all not every user let you to track him (adblock is preventing its users to be tracked).
As for now please just reply if you are sure that users got back to Magento's success page.
To get a much better overview of yours customer behaviour I would recommend you to install this extension [Fooman Google Analytics Plus](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-googleanalyticsplus.html) and set up proper funnels (you'll find brief instruction at extensions page)

Comment: Hi Jemoon thanks for getting back to me, yes we are using the One Step Checkout with Sagepay direct integration, both orders would of gone straight from the checkout to succcess.

I will give the fooman extension a go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check the formating of data passed to GA :

- prices should be formated as "1200000.00" : no separator for thousands, dot as decimal separator, no currency
- text values should be escaped properly quotes contained in them: 'That\s it'

The Fooman extension is a good start since the basic GA implementation in Magento is a shame of non sense, while not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Google tracking in Magento :

Open the Magento Admin area and navigate to System->Configuration->Sales->Google API.
Expand the Google Analytics section.
Pick the Yes option from the Enable drop-down menu. Enter the Google Analytics account number in the Account number field. Click on the Save Config button.

Thanks..!!